ROS Noetic Message Filter Time Synchronizer
i want to ask about application of message_filters::TimeSynchronizer. I try to implement it on my code, but it won't trigger the callback function. Bellow is my code, my device spec and some result when run my ROS project
Device Spec

Nvidia Jetson Orin AGX 32 GB
Ubuntu 20 LTS
ROS Noetic

Subscriber Node
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/stitching.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>
#include "camera_radar_fusion/cameraCaptureTest.h"

class capture_save_image
{
private:
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    ros::Subscriber sub_;
    image_transport::ImageTransport it_;
    image_transport::Publisher image_pub;
    ros::Publisher pub;

    message_filters::Subscriber<camera_radar_fusion::cameraCaptureTest> sub_0_, sub_1_, sub_2_;
    message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<camera_radar_fusion::cameraCaptureTest, camera_radar_fusion::cameraCaptureTest, camera_radar_fusion::cameraCaptureTest> sync_;

    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr_0_;
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr_1_;
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr_2_;

    cv::Mat img_source0, img_source1, img_source2;
    int timestamp = 0;
    std::string path = "/home/roisc-orin/camera_radar_stitch_ws/src/captured_image/";
    std::stringstream name0;
    std::stringstream name1;
    std::stringstream name2;
    bool save0 = false, save1 = false, save2 = false;
    uint8_t frame_interval = 5;
    int file_number = 0;

    int receivedTimestamp0 = 0, receivedTimestamp1 = 0, receivedTimestamp2 = 0;

public:
    capture_save_image()
        : it_(nh_),
          sub_0_(nh_, "/camera0", 50),
          sub_1_(nh_, "/camera1", 50),
          sub_2_(nh_, "/camera2", 50),
          sync_(sub_0_, sub_1_, sub_2_, 50)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor\n";
        pub = nh_.advertise<camera_radar_fusion::cameraCaptureTest>("sync_node", 50);
        sync_.registerCallback(boost::bind(&capture_save_image::cameraCapture_callback, this, _1, _2, _3));
    }

    ~capture_save_image()
    {
        cv::destroyAllWindows();
    }

    void cameraCapture_callback(const camera_radar_fusion::cameraCaptureTestConstPtr msg0, const camera_radar_fusion::cameraCaptureTestConstPtr msg1, const camera_radar_fusion::cameraCaptureTestConstPtr msg2)
    {
        std::cout << "=======================\n";
        cv_ptr_0_ = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg0->Image, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8); 
        cv_ptr_1_ = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg1->Image, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8); 
        cv_ptr_2_ = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg2->Image, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8); 

        if (msg0 == nullptr || msg1 == nullptr || msg2 == nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "One of The Message is Empty\n";
        }

        receivedTimestamp0 = msg0->timestamp;
        receivedTimestamp1 = msg1->timestamp;
        receivedTimestamp2 = msg2->timestamp;

        std::cout << "Received Timestamp 0 = " << receivedTimestamp0 << "\n";
        std::cout << "Received Timestamp 1 = " << receivedTimestamp1 << "\n";
        std::cout << "Received Timestamp 2 = " << receivedTimestamp2 << "\n";

        std::cout << "Received Timestamp camera0 = " << cv_ptr_0_->header.stamp.nsec << "\n";
        std::cout << "Received Timestamp camera1 = " << cv_ptr_1_->header.stamp.nsec << "\n";
        std::cout << "Received Timestamp camera2 = " << cv_ptr_2_->header.stamp.nsec << "\n";

        std::cout << "Header timestamp 0 = " << msg0->header.stamp << "\n";
        std::cout << "Header timestamp 1 = " << msg1->header.stamp << "\n";
        std::cout << "Header timestamp 2 = " << msg2->header.stamp << "\n";

        pub.publish(*msg0);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "Image_Saving_Node");
    capture_save_image cap;
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}

Result
rostopic Hz /camera0
subscribed to [/camera0]
average rate: 25.048
    min: 0.013s max: 0.067s std dev: 0.00790s window: 25
average rate: 25.014
    min: 0.013s max: 0.067s std dev: 0.00591s window: 50
average rate: 24.976
    min: 0.013s max: 0.067s std dev: 0.00561s window: 75
average rate: 24.986
    min: 0.013s max: 0.067s std dev: 0.00562s window: 100
average rate: 24.986
    min: 0.013s max: 0.067s std dev: 0.00534s window: 125
average rate: 24.987
    min: 0.013s max: 0.067s std dev: 0.00496s window: 150
average rate: 25.005
    min: 0.013s max: 0.067s std dev: 0.00485s window: 175
average rate: 24.980
    min: 0.013s max: 0.067s std dev: 0.00468s window: 200


rostopic Hz /camera1
subscribed to [/camera1]
average rate: 25.023
    min: 0.034s max: 0.044s std dev: 0.00179s window: 25
average rate: 25.012
    min: 0.033s max: 0.045s std dev: 0.00224s window: 50
average rate: 25.005
    min: 0.026s max: 0.050s std dev: 0.00282s window: 75
average rate: 25.007
    min: 0.026s max: 0.050s std dev: 0.00275s window: 100
average rate: 25.006
    min: 0.026s max: 0.050s std dev: 0.00290s window: 125
average rate: 25.003
    min: 0.026s max: 0.050s std dev: 0.00300s window: 150
average rate: 25.002
    min: 0.023s max: 0.057s std dev: 0.00337s window: 175

rostopic hz /camera2
subscribed to [/camera2]
average rate: 21.802
    min: 0.021s max: 0.096s std dev: 0.01812s window: 21
average rate: 23.535
    min: 0.012s max: 0.096s std dev: 0.01473s window: 46
average rate: 23.969
    min: 0.012s max: 0.096s std dev: 0.01220s window: 71
average rate: 24.268
    min: 0.012s max: 0.096s std dev: 0.01066s window: 97
average rate: 24.437
    min: 0.012s max: 0.096s std dev: 0.00977s window: 122
average rate: 24.495
    min: 0.012s max: 0.096s std dev: 0.00910s window: 146
average rate: 24.588
    min: 0.012s max: 0.096s std dev: 0.00859s window: 172
average rate: 24.647
    min: 0.012s max: 0.096s std dev: 0.00807s window: 197
average rate: 24.682
    min: 0.012s max: 0.096s std dev: 0.00772s window: 222

rosrun subscriber_node

As you can see in the result above, the three publisher node actually publish each topic (/camera0 , /camera1, /camera2). But, when i run the subscriber node, it stuck on Constructor.I tried other method such as message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime, it work but i still need more stricter synchronization which is why i use message_filters::TimeSynchronizer. Any help will be appreciated and let me know if you need more data / code
Thanks

Do you understand that ExactTime policy means the entire timestamp must match, down to the nanosecond?
